# Print office file (.doc, .docx, .xls) in angular

Tags: angular, excel, iframe, printing, doc

I have the office files url links (.doc, .xls) in angular. Want to print the file content on click of a button.

I tried the below code but it is downloading the file instead of printing and showing this print window without content

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZg1b.png)

```
this.http.get(`${fileUrl}`, options).subscribe((res: any) => {
      /* istanbul ignore next */
      if (res) {
        let blob = new Blob([res], {type: res.type});
        const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        const iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.src = blobUrl;
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        iframe.contentWindow.focus();
        iframe.contentWindow.print();
      }
 });
```

but incase of pdf, img and text file urls above code is working fine and showing the content also in print window.

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjn0d.png)

**files url - **

for pdf file-
https://somepath/testpdf4afdd7ea-5b55-44f4-af2d-f30767764ca9.pdf

for doc file -
https://somepath/file-sample_100kB8de49893-0e1c-4b8f-8f50-fac5e9fc759f.doc

Any help would be very usefull thanks

I want to print the office file (it can be doc, excel, ppt) through it's url in angular.
I already have working code for pdf, img, and text files.

Comment: First you need something to display the contents of the file. Check out this demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-read-and-export-excel-demo?file=README.md

Comment: Then you can use the browser's print API (like you are already doing) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print  (Content window inherits from window) Sry for the dbl comment, apparently you can only edit comments for 5 minutes